# Check which datetime is older if they have different format PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

How to check which date is older if they have different format, for example :

```
$date1 = "2018-05-09 12:31:51"; // "Y-m-d H:i:s" format
$date2 = "06/09/2018"; // "d/m/Y" format
```

Comment: Is the time important? Because `2018-05-09 12:00:00` is before `2018-05-09 13:00:00`, but has the same date.

Comment: you can assume the time variable in `$date2` equal to `00:00:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is pretty handy here

Try this:

```
$date1 = "2018-05-09 12:31:51"; // "Y-m-d H:i:s" format
$date2 = "06/09/2018"; // "d/m/Y" format

$objDateA = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);
$objDateB = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date2);


if ($objDateA < $objDateB)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: where should i put my `$date1` and `$date2` variable?

Comment: i've updated my answer

Comment: how to make the `$date2` variable has the same `$date1` `H:i:s`

Comment: for the same format ? do this `echo $objDateB->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` , if you want the same time `$objDateB->setTime($objDateA->format('H'), $objDateA->format('i'), $objDateA->format('s'));`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a library called Carbon. (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

You can do it like this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$date1 = "2018-05-09 12:31:51";
$date1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:i:s', $date1);

$date2 = "06/09/2018"; // "d/m/Y" format
$date2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date2);

if ($date1 < $date2) {
     echo "Date 1 is older than Date 2";
else {
     echo "Date 1 is newer than Date 2";
}
```

Comment: The entire API you're using is inherited from PHP's DateTime class, so even easier is not using Carbon for this case.

Comment: I recommended this library because it has useful methods to use with dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$date1_dt = new DateTime($date1);
$date2_dt = new DateTime($date2);

if ($date1_dt > $date2_dt) 
 { /* Do something */ }
```

It might possible that the date string is not supported by DateTime parser so you can initialize your dates like this.

```
$date1_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);
$date2_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date2);

 if ($date1_dt > $date2_dt) 
 { /* Do something */ }
```